# Updating mongoose timestamp without actually changing the document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm building a chat application with Mongoose and I have two Models:

Conversation: {
participants [user1,user2],
updatedAt,
createdAt
}

AND

Message: {
conversationId:,
content:''
...
}

I'm using paginate to retrieve 20 documents from Conversation with the latest sent messages

```
let conversations = await Conversation.paginate(
          {participants: userID},
          {
           //select: '_id participants updatedAt createdAt',
            populate: {
              path: 'participants',
              select: 'name lastName _id photoURL'
            },
            page: page,
            limit: 20,
            sort: {updatedAt: -1}
          }
        );
```

When a new message is sent a new Message Document is created. However this will not update the Conversation "updatedAt" value.

In order for the code above to work I need to update the updatedAt value in the Conversation document every time a new message is sent.

**My Question:**

Is there a performance-light way to update the updatedAt value in the Conversation document every time a message document is created?